# highcharts from HTML table does not getting the x axis key

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using a highcharts to draw chart from HTML table , my problem is i want to custom the tooltip but the "this.x" or "this.key" returned as decimal number not as string, how can I get the x axis value as it is??

and that's my code:

```
 Highcharts.chart('ChartContainer', {
            data: {
                table: 'tblData'
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            tooltip: {

                useHTML: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return GetCustomTooltip(this.series.name, this.y, firstSeriesToolTip, firstTooltipTitle, secondTooltipTitle, this.zvalue);
                }
            }
        });

 function GetCustomTooltip(xvalue, yvalue, TooltipArray, firstTooltipTitle, secondTooltipTitle, zvalue, thirdTooltipTitle) {
        var tooltipMessage = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < TooltipArray.length; i++) {
            if (TooltipArray[i][0]== xvalue) {
                tooltipMessage += '<b>' + xvalue + '</b><br>';
                tooltipMessage += firstTooltipTitle + ': ' + '<b>' + yvalue + '</b><br>';
                if (secondTooltipTitle != null)
                    tooltipMessage += secondTooltipTitle + ': ' + '<b>' + TooltipArray[i][1] + '</b><br>';
                if (thirdTooltipTitle != null)
                    tooltipMessage += thirdTooltipTitle + ': ' + '<b>' + TooltipArray[i][3] + '</b><br>';
                break;
            }
        }
        return tooltipMessage;
    }
```

[image: and that's the chart:]

and the table I build it dynamically before draw the chart.

Comment: It is not clear, you want `this.y` and `this.key` to be numbers or string ?

Comment: I want it to be as a string but highcharts automatically convert it to number

Comment: Give an example of what it should be and what Highcharts gives you, for a given `y` and `key`

Comment: what I should get: this.key="january/2018" ,what I actually get : this.key=1538352000000

Answer (score 0):

I got the right values when I change the xAxis type to category